# EEA family permit delayed

Tags: visas, uk, family, entry-permit

I applied for EEA Family permit from italy and i have permesso di soggiorno, but I didn’t received my passport yet (44 days) while they said in my appointment 3 to 4 weeks! I contact with home office 1 month ago and they said the decision has taken and i should just wait for email regarding my passport delivery! and now after 1 month nothing change! Do you have any idea guys is it normal to take that long time because of COVID-19 or it means something else, any advice from your experience guys?

Comment: You should bear in mind that the EEA family permit will not be valid after December 31st.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know whether this is normal, but it certainly is not supposed to be normal.  The whole process shouldn't take more than a couple of weeks.  You should be wary of the possibility that they are trying to prevent you from arriving in the UK before the end of this year.  If I were you I would do everything I could to get my passport as quickly as possible.

(If you are trying to move to the UK, your EEA family member can go to the UK before the end of the year, without you, apply for the EU Settlement Scheme, and after your family member is granted settled or pre-settled status you can apply for an EUSS family permit.  Also, if you are trying to move to the UK then you should be using (Expatriates)[https://expatriates.stackexchange.com] instead of this site.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answering, yes when they delay, we find other solution, and now my eea family member has already granted status under eu settlement scheme, but i still cannot take any further step with my passport, what you suggest?